Tensorflow RNN classification with paragraph instead of word sequences
I have a corpus of documents + labels, where each document is 60+ pages in length and consists of hundreds of individual paragraphs; I'd like to build a Tensorflow RNN classification model off of this dataset, roughly in line with the Tensorflow RNN classification tutorial.
To benefit from the RNN, I'd like to treat each paragraph in a document as if were a word in a sentence, such that the RNN input for a given document is a sequence of paragraph vectors instead of word vectors—e.g., [E[p1], E[p2], E[p3], ...], on the model of [E[The], E[cat], E[on], E[the], E[mat]].
The question is, is there a way to set things up in Tensorflow such that the model learns paragraph embeddings where it would usually learn word embeddings? I know that I could use pre-trained embeddings, but my documents are from a somewhat specialized domain, so training them up as part of  model training seems more appropriate.
I haven't been able to find any relevant information online, nor any questions on Stackoverflow that address this situation.

When we talk about an 'embedding', be it a word embedding or a paragraph embedding, it is akin to a hashmap that transforms some input into a vector of numbers that can be tuned automatically by some downstream model, e.g. a Neural Network.
In your case, if you used paragraph embeddings, your hashmap keys would be the paragraph texts themselves, and you would run into the issue that your keys are too-high-dimensional, i.e. the same paragraph of text would never appear twice, which defeats the purpose of all tuning.
I think in this case a pretrained embedding that is powerful enough to encapsulate your specific use case would probably be the best way to go, but if you really want classification at the paragraph level, perhaps you could use some pooling or aggregation function to aggregate individual word embeddings in a paragraph into a "pooled paragraph embedding"? Perhaps Bag-of-Words would help you achieve this.

This makes sense; thanks! I guess another option might be to pre-train BERT. That would get me domain-specific embeddings at the paragraph level, which I could then pass in as sequences to the RNN as planned.

Pre-training BERT is an option, but it will still yield one output embedding per token (where token = e.g. word). You would still need to decide how to obtain domain-specific embeddings at the paragraph level from these token-level embeddings.

I found this resource which might be useful to you: https://osanseviero.github.io/hackerllama/blog/posts/sentence_embeddings/
